# Cherry-pick fails via Gerrit UI but succeeds via local git-cherry-pick

Tags: git, gerrit, jgit

```
Gerrit version: 2.12.4
Git version: 1.7.9.5

Project Options
Submit Type: Merge if Necessary
Allow content merges: false
Create a new change for every commit not in the target branch: false
```

Cherry-pick a commit onto the target branch fails due to 'merge conflict' in Gerrit. So we do it in the local to see what the conflict is.

Clone the repository. Checkout the target branch. No new commit has been submitted. Copy and paste the cherry-pick command `git fetch ssh://foo refs/changes/xx/yyyxx/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD` with no extra options. The cherry-pick does not fail and there is no conflict. Push, review and submit. Done. So it works well via local git commands.

I make a test. If I set `Allow content merges` to true, no such conflict. But 'allow content merges' as true is not expected because it sometimes solves a minor conflict in a wrong way.

I'd like to know if someone has ever encountered a similar case, and why the cherry-pick behaves differently in Gerrit and in the local repo.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally you're using Git but Gerrit uses [JGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git#Implementations)... maybe there're some difference between them in the merge strategy or probably it's just a bug in JGit.

Comment: If JGit is okay but Git fails, I may blame the merge strategy. It seems no option of git-cherry-pick can make an expectedly successful cherry-pick fail. So I'm wondering if it's a bug.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I almost forgot this question. Later we found it's a bug of JGit. After Gerrit adopts a newer version of JGit, the problem is gone.

Comment: Can someone point me to the JGit bug? I am seeing a similar issue and wanted to check on what version it is fixed.